# Apache2 Vhost attributes

Tags: apache

I am learning how to create a Virtual Host on my apache2 server, in my *-vhost.conf I have the following  attributes:

```
ServerName:
ServerAlias
Alias
DocumentRoot -> Points to where the project files are...?
CustomLog -> Points to where my customLog file is..?
ErrorLog -> Points to Apache2 error Log..?
DirectoryIndex:
BrowserMatch:
DeflateFilterNote:
LogFormat:
CustomLog: Decleared 2 times but different path...?
Options:
SetEnv:
SetEnvIfNoCase:
```

Can someone Explain these in the lamest terms, I did of course google these but I could not find a simple answer....

The Main attributes and their purpose I would like to know about are:

```
ServerName
ServerAlias
Alias
DocumentRoot
```

Comment: That's because there isn't a simple answer. There's no substitution for spending a few hours reading and trying the various things. The four attributes you end with are probably the simplest to understand. If you can't understand the way they're explained at the [apache site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) I'm not sure anyone here will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to read some things about Apache Web Server and Virtual Hosts.
You can start from here:

- [Apache Virtual Host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)
- [Apache Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html)

Comment: Thank you Will have a read through these and let you know how they helped me :)